# "Could not find or load main class" Exporting jar file from eclipse and created custom manifest.txt

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

Manifest.txt file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.persistence.tutorial.MyLibrary
Class-Path: xstream-1.2.2.jar
```

created test.jar contains all class files with custom manifest.txt opened using winrar in meta-inf file contains code same as manifest.txt file have.

error getting while this test.jar file running using cmd error
"Could not find or load main class **pacakgename.mainclassname**"

anyone please suugest why i am getting error

Comment: Does "org.persistence.tutorial.MyLibrary" have a public static void main(String[]) method?

Comment: yes,main method is in MyLibrary class